# Suppress open associate perspective wizard for RCP

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, rcp, eclipse-juno

I'm creating an RCP application in that application a reusing eclipse 3.x component using compatibility layer. 
In my RCP I added project explorer but the problem is when I create one javaScript project using Explorer than at the end **Open associate perspective ?** wizard come.

[image]

So is there is any way to Suppress that wizard from my RCP application.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a preference customization to your product definition:

```
<property
    name="preferenceCustomization"
    value="platform:/plugin/com.example.rcp.product/plugin_customization.ini">
</property>
```

In your product plugin (i.e. above: com.example.rcp.product) create a file named `plugin_customization.ini`.

Add the following contents

```
org.eclipse.ui.ide/SWITCH_PERSPECTIVE_ON_PROJECT_CREATION=never
```

This will suppress the prompt in your question's image.